# rsync : transferring files in one direction only

Tags: linux, rsync, synchronization

Is it possible to use rsync to copy files in one direction only?

For example, suppose we have:

`left/a.txt`

`right/a.txt`

where the files are initially identical.

If one then modifies `right/a.txt`, then:

`rsync -avv left/ right/`

will copy `right/a.txt` onto `left/a.txt`.

Is it possible to restrict rsync to only copying from `left/` to `right/` (i.e. prevent it from copying from `right/` to `left/`)?

Answer (score 45):

You misunderstand rsync. This command:

```
rsync -avv left/ right/
```

will not sync anything in right to left. It will, as @atbg says, only sync left to right. Rsync is not a bi-directional syncer. It syncs the dest with the source.

Man page for reference: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: Interestingly when operating at least the Mac version of rsync to sync remote directory via ssh it is bidirectional - e.g. `rsync -avzz -e "ssh -p 2222" /source/ /target/`

Answer (score 4):

It should be `rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]` so it does work in that direction (unless you switch dest and src).

`left/a.txt` should be copied to `right/a.txt`:

```
$ echo 'left' > left/a.txt
$ echo 'right' > right/a.txt
$ cat left/a.txt && cat right/a.txt
left
right
$ rsync -avv left/ right/
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
a.txt
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=5

sent 95 bytes  received 34 bytes  258.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5  speedup is 0.04
$ cat left/a.txt && cat right/a.txt
left
left
```

If there are specific files you don't want included by rsync take a look at `--exclude=PATTERN` and `--exclude-from=FILE`.

Comment: And remember, when in doubt the `--dry-run` option will show you a list of the files that would have been transferred but not actually perform the transfer. I add this to the start of every `rsync` just as a precaution, even if I am sure the command is correct.

Comment: Given the confusion about rsync's operation, it is perhaps worth noting rsync's `--update` option, which will skip (not sync) files which have a more recent `modified` time on the receiving side.